# How to set attribute in loop from array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, loops

I had simple one dimensional array

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

I want to create a loop that will change single div id to new id from my array:

**From**

```
<div id="120"></div>
<div id="121"></div>
<div id="122"></div>
<div id="123"></div>
<div id="124"></div>
```

**To**

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="5"></div>
```

That how I get id attribute from div:

```
var divId = $("div").attr('id');
```

How to do that in jQuery or JS?

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried? Where, and *how*, did your attempt(s) fail? Try looking at array methods such as [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or, for jQuery, the [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) method, as a start.

Comment: Why would you want to do this.  This seems to me to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858) thus not a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var allDiv = document.querySelectorAll('div');
allDiv.forEach(function(item, i){
  item.setAttribute('id', array[i]);
});

console.log(document.querySelectorAll('div'))
```

```html
<div id="120"></div>
<div id="121"></div>
<div id="122"></div>
<div id="123"></div>
<div id="124"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can do this by:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
$("div").each(function(i, object){
    $(this).attr("id", array[i]);
});
```

But if you are trying to number them, you don't really need the array. You can just do it like this:

```
$("div").each(function(i, object){
    $(this).attr("id", i);
});
```

Anyways, I hope that helps :D

Comment: Bear in mind that in JavaScript the numbering/indices will start from 0 rather than 1; this may, or may not, be of importance to the OP.